# Override a Control's events from a helper class

Tags: c#, events, controls, overriding

I know that when I subclass a Control I have the choice of overriding an event or subscribing to it:

```
public class myPanel : Panel 
{
    public myPanel()
    {
        this.Paint += myPanel_Paint;
    }

    void myPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

}
```

My question is **not** about subclassing but about creating a helper class, to which a regular control instance can be registered. Now I can subscribe to its events:

```
class DrawCtl
{
   public Control CTL { get; set;}

public DrawCtl(Control Ctl) 
{
    CTL = Ctl;
    CTL.MouseMove += CTL_MouseMove;
}

void CTL_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

What I'd like to know is: Is it also possible to `override` a Control's event from the helper class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. You want to override an event member like MouseMove on the CTL variable? What are you trying to achieve? You want to change the add/remove parts of the event?

Comment: can you tell me the `OnPaint` function is `protected` or not? usually this method is `protected`...

Comment: @Mehdi: I guess that's the answer, and it is 'no'.

Comment: Then I have to put this for answer :) are you agree? :D @TaW

Comment: yes, do it. all onXXX methods are protected

Comment: @Bedford: What I'm building atm is a helper class that takes care of tedious things you always need when writing even the simplest mouse interactions, like a doodling programm. Or a tracer. Or a vector editor.. From managing Point lists, drawing actions to catching the mouse events..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnPaint` method is usually `protected`; all `OnXXX` event methods are `protected`, too. You can `override` and use it only in the derived classes; so you can't do this in a helper class...

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot "override an event", overriding is only possible on virtual methods in a base class.  The point of events is the *exact* opposite, breaking this kind of dependency between classes.  It strongly empowers the component-based programming model of .NET.  The huge advantage is that *any* class can subscribe the event.  Ones you don't have to know about, nor have to be available yet.

They do have a disadvantage, they can easily break your class.  You empower other code to mess up your painting.  Which isn't your bug of course, you might however well get a support call about it :)

Which is also the reason that you should **always** override OnPaint() in your class, *never* use the Paint event.  Because now you really *want* the coupling and be in control, reducing the odds that accidents occurs.  You have a decision to make, and you should stick to it so your control behaves predictably.  The choice you have to make is when to call base.OnPaint().

You have four choices.  Call it first, then do your own painting.  Makes you the boss, your paint is always on top.  Or do your own painting, then call base.OnPaint().  Hands the baton to the client code and the "friendly" component-oriented way.  Or put your foot down and don't call it at all.  So no Paint event handler can mess it up.  And the ultimate weapon, declare it *sealed* so nobody can override your OnPaint() method either.  Never a surprise that way :)

Comment: As usual, interesting comments. Not quite on topic, though, since I __don't__ want to subclass at all.